# How to declare multiple properties with DRY principle in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, properties, dry

Here is a thing, I have class that gets data from a server. I use properties, because I want these data to be easily accessible from an instance of the class and I want to check if I has already been saving these data. These data I get from one place, therefore I'm using the same function to fetch data for each property.

So it looks something like the following:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self._data = {}

    def _get_data(self):
        function_name = inspect.stack()[1][3]
        data_name = function_name
        try:
            return self._data[data_name]
        except KeyError:
            response = http_client.get(server + '/?data=' + data_name)
            self._data[data_name] = response.data
            return response.data

    @property
    def prop1(self):
        return self._get_data()

    @property
    def prop2(self):
        return self._get_data()

    @property
    def prop3(self):
        return self._get_data()

    @property
    def prop4(self):
        return self._get_data()

    @property
    def prop5(self):
        return self._get_data()
```

I don't want to copy-paste code like that. What would you do about that?

Alternative is to load all properties to dictionary in `__init__` and then it would be accessible like `obj.data['prop1']`. However that's ugly and instantiation would take a lot of time.

Further I thought about dealing with it with help of a metaclass. That's a little better solution.

```
class MyMetaClass(type):
    def __new__(mcs, name, bases, attrs, **kwargs):
        for prop in attrs['properties']:
            attrs[prop] = property(attrs['_get_prop'](prop))

        return super().__new__(mcs, name, bases, attrs)


class MyClass(metaclass=MyMetaClass):
    properties = ('prop1', 'prop2', 'prop3', 'prop4', 'prop5')

    def __init__(self):
        self._data = {}

    def _get_prop(prop):
        def _get_data(self):
            data_name = prop
            try:
                return self._data[data_name]
            except KeyError:
                response = http_client.get(server + '/?data=' + data_name)
                self._data[data_name] = response.data
                return response.data
        return _get_data
```

However I think that using metaclasses to solve this simple problem could be a bit overkill. Can you think of some better way?

Comment: You can run that loop setting attributes directly on the class without the metaclass, either in top-level code after the class declaration, or in a decorator. Anyway, it's worth noting that the former method, although repetitive, plays much nicer with IDEs and linters. If I was dealing with your code (e.g. as a library) I would much prefer you used that method.